# Arcgis javascript tutorials help

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, references

I'm going through some of the javascript tutorials - build your first application. It works fine when I create an html file that holds the style and script tags but when I separate the files out to html, js and css the map can only be seen over half the screen. I've tried a few things but I can't get the map to full extent like it should be...should I tweak the css?

```
html, body, #map {
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }
     body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the link to the css file is correct?

if no css is available the map does not cover the page.

this works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="map.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/esri/css/esri.css">
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) { 
            map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                center: [-56.049, 38.485],
                zoom: 3,
                basemap: "streets"
            });
        });
    </script>


    <title></title>
</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

But if I remove the link to map.css I get the same problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="map.css">
```